# Format text in sphinx table cells

Tags: python-sphinx

I have a table I am generating in sphinx for comparing constructs in different languages.  I would like to have the cells contain code blocks in each language and have it come out looking like code (at least in a monospaced font).  What I have so far is:

```
+-----------------------------+------------------------+
| Haskell                     | Scala                  |
+=============================+========================+
| | do var1<- expn1           | | for {var1 <- expn1;  |
| |    var2 <- expn2          | |      var2 <- expn2;  |
| |    expn3                  | |      result <- expn3 |
|                             | | } yield result       |
+-----------------------------+------------------------+
| | do var1 <- expn1          | | for {var1 <- expn1;  |
| |    var2 <- expn2          | |      var2 <- expn2;  |
| |    return expn3           | | } yield expn3        |
+-----------------------------+------------------------+
| | do var1 <- expn1 >> expn2 | | for {_ <- expn1;     |
| |    return expn3           | |      var1 <- expn2   |
|                             | | } yield expn3        |
+-----------------------------+------------------------+
```

This, at least preserves line breaks but it comes out in the same font as the rest of the document which is a little annoying.

Is there any way to convert the cells to some better format?

Comment: it didn't work to surround the text with double-backquotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try using the [`.. code-block::` directive](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/code.html)?

This works fine on my PC using Sphinx 1.4.1:

```
 +----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
 | Tweedledee                       | Tweedledum                       |
 +----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
 | .. code-block:: c                | .. code-block:: c                |
 |    :caption: foo.c               |    :caption: bar.c               |
 |                                  |                                  |
 |    extern int bar(int y);        |    extern int foo(int x);        |
 |    int foo(int x)                |    int bar(int y)                |
 |    {                             |    {                             |
 |       return x > 0 ? bar(x-1)+1  |       return y > 0 ? foo(x-1)*2  |
 |                    : 0;          |                    : 0;          |
 |    }                             |    }                             |
 +----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Jason, I'll give this a try.